# Link a child container running inside a parent container

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I have an ubuntu:16.04 container running with docker cli installed. I'm able to run a node container inside the ubuntu container but unable to access it. 
Getting the following errors 
"Could not resolve host: node-server"
"Connection refused"

I was trying to access the node-container from the ubuntu container. Is there any way to link ubuntu container to node container.

DockerFile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install docker-cli & curl

COPY start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "start.sh"]
```

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run -d -p 4020:4020 --name my-node node-service

curl http://my-node:4020
```

I was expecting to connect to the node-service through ubuntu container. Am I missing anything??

Comment: Two issues: if you're starting containers with `docker run`, both need to be on the same (non-default) `--net`; and the first container can't start the second, a host-level process needs to start both of them.